# Make .find non case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can currently using:

```
$results.find('a[href$=".doc"]')
```

to find anything ending with .doc for editing reasons.  However, this seems to be case sensitive, i.e. if a document ends with .DOC or .Doc, it will not find those.  Is it possible to make this non case sensitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a function to match case insensitively.

```
$results.find('a').filter(function(){return /\.doc$/i.test(this.href);});
```

It is also possible to enumerate all 8 cases in the selector, but this won't scale easily.

```
$results.find('a[href$=".doc"],a[href$=".doC"],a[href$=".dOc"],a[href$=".dOC"],a[href$=".Doc"],a[href$=".DoC"],a[href$=".DOc"],a[href$=".DOC"]')
```

Comment: +1 - This is your best bet, making another attribute selector isn't pretty, and won't be as efficient either.

Answer (score 0):

try this i am not sure :

```
$results.find("a:regex(href, /\.doc$/i)")
```

but this will work for all a tags so u can use it with $results somehow

```
$("a:regex(href, /\.doc$/i)")
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/